# ActiveRecord hating a particular column? (Bizarre)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been working on a web app lately, and Activerecord has started creeping me out- for the most part it's awesome, but it has taken to treating a particular column like a leper.

Initially I created a student model from a scaffold. The model holds various information like name, email, entry quarter, etc. And that all works beautifully. The problem I'm having is in how it's taken to treating a particular column- a string named type. Type is supposed to have a value like "B.S.", "M.S", "PhD", etc, however, neither creating a new object instance nor editing an old one are able to change the value from ''. Furthermore, if I go into the database and manually change the value, Rails throws a fit and throws errors when I call Student.find.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'type' is a protected column in activerecord for the purpose of inheritance. Oops!

Comment: mark this as the answer even though you answered it yourself.

Comment: I will- apparently there's a cooldown time though. Gotta wait 2 days.